# No puedo borrar un archivo con Node.js try/catch/finally

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

Estoy creando un código QR, pero al final no puedo borrarlo. Esta es mi estructura de carpetas

```
-back-end
 -codes
 -dist
 -node_modules
 -public
 -src
  -models
  -...
  -routes
 -uploads
```

Está escrito con Typescript, por lo que necesito compilar, así `tsc -w` para escuchar cambios. Esto me crea la carpeta `dist` Eso es el bundle en Javascript que puede leer node. Estoy usando `nodemon` para levantar la instancia, lo ejecuto así `nodemon dist`. Ya en producción la cosa cambia y lo hago distinto, pero hasta aquí vamos bien.

Estoy Express para crear la API
**routes/qr-code.route.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { signInMiddleware } from '../../middlewares/auth.middleware';
import { toFile } from 'qrcode';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import fs from 'fs';
import { logger } from '../../functions/winston.util';

const DispatchQrcodeRoute = Router();
const unLinkFile = promisify( fs.unlink )
    
DispatchQrcodeRoute.get( '/', [signInMiddleware], async ( req: Request, res: Response ) => {
    const url = String( req.query.url );
    const name = `codes/${new Date().getTime()}.png`;
    try {
        await toFile( `${ name }`, url );
        console.log(name);
        res.contentType('png');
        res.download( name );
        console.log('Descargando');
    } catch ( e: any ){
        logger.error( 'QRCODE - SAVE IMAGE' + e.error );
    } finally {
        if( fs.existsSync( name ) ) {
            console.log('Borrando');
            await unLinkFile( name );
        }
    }
    
});

export default DispatchQrcodeRoute;
```

Hasta aquí funciona, hace lo que tiene que hacer, me crea una imagen QR y la descarga a quien lo pidió. El problema es que la carpeta de `codes` se está llenando de códigos, quiero borrarlos así que agregué un `finally`

```
finally {
        if( fs.existsSync( name ) ) {
            await unLinkFile( name );
        }
    }
```

Ahora tengo un error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\projects\foo\bar\back-end\codes\1638464387554.png'
```

Puse un par de `console.log` para saber que estaba haciendo y este fue el resultado

```
codes\1638464652208.png
Descargando
Borrando
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\projects\foo\bar\back-end\codes\1638464652208.png'
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: @Trauma el callback es opcional en E6/ES7, el OP usa Typescript y `async / await` por lo cual, en principio debe funcionar. ;)

Comment: Por otro lado, el problema no está en la libreria QR, el tema **tal vez** va más por el uso de `promisify` sobre `fs.unlink`. No necesitas esa utilidad (`promisify`) si usas Node v10.0.0 o superior, ya que dispones de [`fsPromises.unlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesunlinkpath). Saludos Alberto.

Comment: Otro problema que es muy común es el intento de acceso de escritura (unlink) sobre archivos que están abiertos para lectura (download). Revisa si acaso te estás encontrando con una *race condition*, al tratar de borrar un archivo que aún no ha terminado de ser enviado al cliente. Aunque el error dice claramente `ENOENT`, tal vez el fichero no ha sido cerrado aún cuando tratas de eliminarlo. Son muchas cosas por determinar.

Comment: Ahora se me ocurre que el error te lo arroja el `response` de Express, tal vez el archivo es borrado antes de poder ser enviado al cliente. En fin, que ya te he dado ideas al respecto. Saludos